I'm trying to wire this motor I have, but I'm not sure how to read this diagram

This motor is 110V or 220V. I'm trying to wire it up for 110 but I'm not 100% sure how. Is low std 110V and high 220V?
I believe I need to connect  1,3,8 to hot and 2,4,5 to neutral and ground to the green screw in the housing.

you are correct in your thinking ... the next line in the table is for opposite direction rotation

Nothing in that table says anything what high and low mean, if they mean 110/220 volts or speed or something else.

Usually "triangle" for lower voltage and "star" for higher. But better to find manufacturer recommendation, because it is not clear the directions of winds.

You are correct.  This is a split-phase, capacitor-start induction motor. It runs from a single phase AC power source.  How it works:
For the higher voltage, the two "A" phase coils are connected in series, and for the lower voltage, the two coils are in parallel.  It is important to follow the table so that the two "A" phase coils are phased correctly.
The "B" phase angle must be shifted from the "A" phase for maximum torque, and it must be derived from the same single phase AC input.  The two capacitors in parallel, in series with phase "B", provide the correct phase shift and give the optimum starting torque at low speed.  But this starting capacitance is not optimum for running.  A lower capacitance results in improved power factor and efficiency at running speed.  So, a centrifugal switch (shown in your drawing) opens when the motor approaches its running speed, and the capacitance is reduced to the value of the single run capacitor.
As @jstola says, reversing the leads on the "B" phase will reverse the direction of the motor.
